# Taking derivative when applying L'Hopital to $f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to make sure I'm doing my derivatives correctly for this, assuming $a,b,c$ are constants and $f(x)$ is thrice differentiable with $f'''$ bounded:

$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}$

I was applying L'Hopital twice, but I'm not 100 percent certain on the derivatives. Is it just:

$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{af''(x-h)+bf''(x)+cf''(x+2h)}{2}=af''(x)+bf''(x)+cf''(x)$, meaning $a+b+c=1$? or do I need to do something with the $h's$ inside the functions when deriving?

Edit:
Attempting the first application again

$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-af'(x-h)+2cf'(x+2h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-af'(x-h)+4cf'(x+2h)}{2}$?

Which Yields $b$ is free, $a=2-4c$?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the Chain Rule, and also make sure L'H applies. For that you will need conditions on $a,b,c$.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that I know $a,b,c$ are constants. As far as the chain rule goes, does that mean 
$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-af'(x)h+bf'(x)+2cf'(x)}{2h}$ for the first application?

Comment: What you're doing is perfect MC, you can use a constant shift rule to deal with those h's. They stay there for each derivative. However, in the last line, you dropped the denominator of 2.

Comment: No, you have to compute the derivative with respect to $h$ and that expression is wrong.

Comment: Oop, right, the limit depends on h. egreg is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might be helpful for you:

$$\frac{d}{dh}af(x - h) = -af'(x - h)$$

$$\frac{d}{dh}bf(x) = 0$$

$$\frac{d}{dh}cf(x + 2h) = 2cf'(x + 2h)$$

Comment: Now if I wanted to solve all the way through for $a,b,c$, then I would get $b$ is free, and $a=2-4c$?

Comment: I get that as well, given that $f''(x) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Write the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x$ to order $2$:
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+h^2R_2(h)
$$
where $\lim_{h\to0}R_2(h)=0$. Then
\begin{align}
f(x-h)&=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)-h^2R_2(-h)\\
f(x+2h)&=f(x)+2hf'(x)+2hf''(x)+4h^2R_2(2h)
\end{align}
so that
$$
\frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}=
\frac{1}{h^2}\left(
  (a+b+c)f(x)+(-a+2c)hf'(x)+
  \left(\frac{a}{2}+2c\right)h^2f''(x)+h^2S(h)
\right)
$$
where
$$
S(h)=-aR_2(-h)+4cR_2(2h)
$$
and $\lim_{h\to0}S(h)=0$.

In order the limit for $h\to0$ is finite, we need:

1. $(a+b+c)f(x)=0$
2. $(-a+2c)f'(x)=0$

If these conditions are satisfied, then the limit is
$$
\left(\frac{a}{2}+2c\right)f''(x)
$$
If $f''(x)\ne0$, saying that the limit is $f''(x)$ forces $a=2-4c$.

If also $f'(x)\ne0$ we get $a=2/3$ and $c=1/3$. If, moreover, $f(x)=0$, we get $b=-1$.

Comment: Would these then make $f'''$ bounded? That is ultimately what I want to work toward, I just wanted to check step by step.

Comment: @MC989 The statement of the problem is not very clear to begin with. As you see, the third derivative has no role here.